# Angular: access FormControl from Directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I would like to add validators dynamically to my FormControl via a custom Directive.

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[idNumber]",
})
export class IdNumberDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor(private formControl: FormControl) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.addValidators(this.formControl);
    }

    addValidators(formControl: FormControl) {
        formControl.setValidators(Validators.compose(
            [Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(3),
            Validators.maxLength(8)
            ]
        ));
    }



<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput
        [formControl]="idNumberFormControl"
        [placeholder]="placeholder"
</mat-form-field>
```

**I don't need to reference the nativeElement (via ElementRef).**

**I would like to reference the formControl**...

...and use it as such:

```
// HTML with my custom directive 'idNumber' ////////
<custom-input-string
    idNumber 
    [name]="'idNumber'"
    [label]="Id Number"
    [placeholder]="">
</custom-input-string>

// TS ////////
@ViewChild(CustomInputStringComponent) child: CustomInputStringComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.child.insertIntoForm(this.signupForm);
    }, 0);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is an example of using a directive to append validators to your form control.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttt2df?file=app%2Fid-number.directive.ts)

Note that using that will result in losing all of your previous validators.

```
constructor(
  // Get the control directive
  private control: NgControl
) { }
ngOnInit() {
  const abstractControl = this.control.control;
  abstractControl && abstractControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
}
```

Comment: hi, doesn't the onEvent fire every single time on valueChanges of the FormControl? I mean, doesn't this event fire every single time a user presses any key while focused in the FormControl? Isn't there a way to check and set these validators in the directive's OnInit method? Thank you.

Comment: Yes it does get triggered at every single keystroke, but the condition in the function prevents the validators from being set several times. This must be done this way because the constructor isn't aware of the control. You can also use ngOnInit(), as in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttt2df?file=app%2Fid-number.directive.ts) which I have update my answer with ( because it's way more clear with it indeed !)

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: This answer works great, but I think that the main aspect (the use of `NgControl` instead of the `FormControl` of the OP) is too valuable to stay in an external link (Stackblitz). I'd suggest we put this part directly in the answer, as did @Suresh in his answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you utilize NgControl and constructor DI injection we can have a directive applicable to form controls from reactive forms in either formControlName or template driven forms:

**Directive:**

```
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) { }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Suresh, thank you for your suggestion, but I need a bit more detailed explanation. Will I be able to do this? this.addValidators(this.control);  Would that work?  PS: I don't use and I will never use 'template driven forms'.

Comment: We can get a reference to the form control instance via DI using NgControl. You can access the Form Control methods using that instance

Comment: could you please update your answer with some more code?. Also - what is the point of the 'private el: ElementRef' in your suggestion?

Comment: @PaxForce In this particular situtation `private el: ElementRef` doesn't do anything, you could leave it out.  But in general, `ElementRef` is passed to every directive so you can access the underlying element and native element like `this.el.nativeElement` would return the HTML element from the DOM. It just like using `ViewChild` in a component to reference an element in the HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and 'cleanest' way is to use `NG_VALIDATORS` provider:

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core'
import { NG_VALIDATORS ValidationErrors, Validator } from '@angular/forms'

@Directive({
  selector: '[myIdValidator]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: IdValidatorDirective, multi: true }
  ],
})
export class IdValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    // your validation here
    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access both FormGroup and FormControl in your directive by **FormGroupDirective**:

NOTE: I'm working on a country selection in this example.

```
import { FormGroupDirective } from "@angular/forms";
```

Then:

```
{
constructor(private fg: FormGroupDirective) { }


// Access the FormGroup
console.log('My FormGroup values: ', this.fg.value);

// Access the FormControl
console.log('The selectedCountryCtrl: ', this.fg.control.controls.selectedCountryCtrl);
console.log('The selectedCountryCtrl value: ', this.fg.control.controls.selectedCountryCtrl.value);

// Access the variable/object directly
console.log('My FormControl selectedCountry value: ', this.fg.value.selectedCountry);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//TestAnythingsComponent.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { IdNumberDirective } from '../directives/IdNumberDirective.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-anythings',
  templateUrl: './test-anythings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-anythings.component.css'],
  providers:[IdNumberDirective]
})
export class TestAnythingsComponent implements OnInit {
  testForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, IdNumberDirective : IdNumberDirective) { 
    this.testForm = fb.group({
      idNumberFormControl : new FormControl(null,
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(3),
            Validators.maxLength(8),
          IdNumberDirective.customValidator()
          ])
        ),
    })
  }
}

//IdNumberDirective.ts

import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[idNumber]'
})
export class IdNumberDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  customValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    Validators.nullValidator
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

      //any condition to check control value
      if (control.value != "Sachin") {
        //return key value pair of errors
        return { "customError": { inValid: true, errMsg: 'Invalid Value' } };
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}


//test-anythings.component.html



    <form [formGroup]="testForm">
      <input idNumber formControlName="idNumberFormControl" />
      <div *ngIf="testForm.get('idNumberFormControl').invalid && testForm.get('idNumberFormControl').errors.customError.inValid"
        style="color:red">
        {{testForm.get('idNumberFormControl').errors.customError.errMsg}}
      </div>
    
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Dear Sachin, could you place some comment to your code to facilitate an understanding of your approach?

Comment: Hi Artem, Look at my above solution, pls enter "Sachin" to disappear error message, I have tried my best, I am new to angular. Thanks.